# How to change MudExpansionPanel's initial state to an expanded state using MudBlazor?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I have created a simple expansion panel using MudBlazor and included it below.

```
    <MudExpansionPanels>
       <MudExpansionPanel>
        <TitleContent>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <MudText>Expansion Panel</MudText>
                
            </div>
        </TitleContent>
        <ChildContent>
            Panel Content
        </ChildContent>
    </MudExpansionPanel>
 </MudExpansionPanels>

@code
{
    
}
```

The default state of the expansion panel is Collapsed. Now I have needed to change its default state as the expanded state. It means when I start the application by default it should be expanded. How to do this using blazor??

Answer (score 7):

I've checked the MudBlazor code and there's a bool Parameter `IsExpanded`.

So this should work:

```
<MudExpansionPanel *IsExpanded=true* IsInitiallyExpanded=true >
  ....
</MudExpansionPanel>
```

### Update

A little further exploration of the code revealed `IsInitiallyExpanded`.

```
[Parameter]
[Category(CategoryTypes.ExpansionPanel.Behavior)]
public bool IsInitiallyExpanded { get; set; }
```

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   //....
 if (!IsExpanded && IsInitiallyExpanded)
    {
        _isExpanded = true;
        _collapseIsExpanded = true;
    }
    Parent?.AddPanel(this);
}
```

And the razor code:

```
<MudCollapse Expanded="@_collapseIsExpanded" MaxHeight="@MaxHeight">
   <div class="@PanelContentClassname">
       @ChildContent
   </div>
</MudCollapse>
```

Comment: yeah great, I also saw this. but I think we can only check that whether the expansion panel is expanded or not by using the IsExpanded attribute. isn't it??

Comment: See my updated answer.  I think `IsInitiallyExpanded` will work!

Comment: Only adding `IsInitiallyExpanded=true` works.

Answer (score 0):

use **IsInitiallyExpanded="true"**

```
<MudExpansionPanels>
<MudExpansionPanel Text="Panel 1" IsInitiallyExpanded="true">
    Panel One Content
</MudExpansionPanel>
<MudExpansionPanel Text="Panel 2">
    Panel Two Content
</MudExpansionPanel>
<MudExpansionPanel Text="Panel 3">
    Panel Three Content
</MudExpansionPanel>
```